# Jquery Div Click for Audio Player?

Tags: jquery, html, audio

So, for a player that I am developing for a website, the album artwork is the background which is pulled from Last.fm via XML JSON and then displayed. Now, currently, the music plays automatically and the player is supposed to hide all player control until the player is clicked, which it will then expand to fit the whole artwork, metadata, and have player controls. An example of the player (without audio for you convenience) can be found [here](http://wpovfm.org/moldycheese/steamingWidget.php). I assume that I can use jQuery for this to work, however, when I tried to write the code for it, nothing worked. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** I'm not looking for how to control the audio, much rather, I need to, *on click*, expand the player, resize the artwork, and display the controls.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title></title>
<style>

#streamingWidgetContainer{
    text-shadow:rgba(125,125,125,0.9)0px 0px 10px;
    z-index: 10;
    transition: ease 1s;
    -webkit-tranisition: ease 1s;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 6%;
    min-height: initial;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    position: fixed;
    margin-right: 3%;
    margin-left: 2.5%;
    width: 12%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.09);
    display: inline;
    text-align: left;
}

#streamingWidgetContainer:hover{
    z-index: 10;
    transition: ease 1s;
    -webkit-tranisition: ease 1s;
    height: 14%;
}
#streamingWidget{
    font-weight: 300;
}

#artwork{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#overlay{
    padding-left: 0.75%;
    padding-top: 1%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgb(58,58,58);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(58,58,58,0.3) 0%, rgba(178,178,178,0.3) 100%); 
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(58,58,58,0.3)), color-stop(100%,rgba(178,178,178,0.3)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(58,58,58,0.3) 0%,rgba(178,178,178,0.3) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(58,58,58,0.3) 0%,rgba(178,178,178,0.3) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(58,58,58,0.3) 0%,rgba(178,178,178,0.3) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(58,58,58,0.3) 0%,rgba(178,178,178,0.3) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#3a3a3a', endColorstr='#b2b2b2',GradientType=0 );
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="streamingWidgetContainer">
        <div id="artwork">
            <div id="overlay">
                <div id="streamingWidgetContents">
        <?php
                                        $json = @file_get_contents('http://wpov.streamon.fm/metadata/events/WPOV-32k.json');
                                        $json = json_decode($json, true);
                                        $artistName = $json["TPE1"];
                                        $trackName = $json["TIT2"];
                                        $albumName = $json["TALB"];
                                        echo '<b>' . $artistName . '</b>' . '<br>';
                                        $artist = $artistName;
                                        echo '<i>' . $trackName . '</i>' . '<br>';
                                        echo "<span style='display: none;'>" . $albumName . "</span>";
                                        $album = $albumName;

                                        /*
                                        Super Special Thanks to: edwardmp 
                                        */

                                        class LastFM {
                                            const API_KEY = "7facb82a2a573dd483d931044030e30c";
                                            public static $size_map = array("small" => 0, "medium" => 1, "large" => 2, "extralarge" => 3, "mega" => 4);

                                            public static function getArtwork($artist, $return_image = false, $size = "mega", $album) {
                                                $artist = urlencode($artist);
                                                $album = urlencode($album);
                                                $size = "mega";
                                                $returnedInfo = "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=album.getinfo&api_key=" . self::API_KEY . "&artist=" . $artist . "&album=" . $album . "&image=" . self::$size_map[$size] . "&format=json";
                                                $returnedInfo = @file_get_contents($returnedInfo);

                                                if(!$returnedInfo) {
                                                    return;
                                                }

                                                $json = json_decode($returnedInfo, true);
                                                $albumArt = $json["album"]["image"][self::$size_map[$size]]["#text"];

                                                if($albumArt == null) {
                                                    $albumArt = "http://wpovfm.org/images/wpovDefaultArtwork.png";
                                                }

                                                return (!$return_image) ? print_r($json) : "<style> #artwork{ background: url('" . $albumArt . "') no-repeat;
            -webkit-background-size: cover;
            -moz-background-size: cover;
            -o-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover; } </style>";
                                            }
                                        }

                                        $artwork = LastFM::getArtwork($artist, true, $size, $album);

                                        if($artwork) {
                                            echo $artwork;
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            return;
                                        }
                                        ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#steamingWidgetContainer").click(function(){
        $("#streamingWidgetContainer").css({"height":"14%"});
        $("#artwork").css({"display":"inline","width":"20%","height":"inherit"});
        $("#overlay").css({"background":"rgba(0,0,0,0)"});
        $("#streamingWidgetContent").css({"position":"absolute","margin-left":"6%"});
    }); 
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Additionally, my goal for the player can be seen [here](http://wpovfm.org/images/playerExpandedControls.png).

Comment: Eric, that's not what I was looking for. But thanks for your help. Look at my link at the end to see what I'm asking for help with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
$('#streamingWidgetContainer').on('click', function() {
    // Change formatting
});
```

Also, why don't you use css classes and add/remove them on the click event?

Comment: Awesome. I didn't think that one through. I'll give it a try and see how it works.